# Can I update a property on all elements directly

Tags: javascript

For example:

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
```

I want to set the `checked` to true on all inputs. Can this be done like in jQuery, without using a for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using pure JavaScript you can use the [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll) function as below:

```
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');

for(var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++) {  checkboxes[i].checked = true; }
```

Unfortunately this doesn't avoid looping which I know you wanted to avoid and It also doesn't have perfect cross browser compatibility as can be checked [here](http://caniuse.com/queryselector) with IE 8 only being able to hook on to CSS 2.1 selectors and Pre IE8 not being supported at all but it's the best that can be done without using lots of code and avoiding jQuery.

I know you want to avoid jQuery but, if you change your mind you can try the following:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', 'checked')
```

This should hook on to any checkbox input and set its attribute to checked using the jQuery `attr()` function.

If this doesn't work try giving your checkboxes their own class name such as checkbox and try like as follows:

```
$('.checkbox').attr('checked', 'checked')
```

This would help with compatibility issues and would avoid looping but if you don't want to go the jQuery route then please ignore.

Comment: I'd like not to use jQuery, because this would be my only javascript in the page...

Comment: Apologies! I mis-read the question, I read can this be done in jQuery not "like" in jQuery... Apologies. Hopefully this can be useful for someone else while I come back with the actual answer shortly!

Comment: What's your thinking behind recommending getElementsByClassName when the question specifies querySelectorAll?

Answer (score 4):

`querySelectorAll` returns a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/NodeList). You will need to iterate over the list to change each item in it (jQuery loops over the entire collection too in the background using .each)

You can either use a loop (for, while, etc) or you could use the `forEach` method on the `Array` prototype

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/NodeList#Workarounds

Answer (score 3):

No, this cannot be done without some form of iteration over the nodes. jQuery iterates over the nodes as well, it just hides it from the user.

The closest that comes to jQuery-like style is using [`.forEach` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) in browser where it is supported:

```
[].forEach.call(inputs, function() {
    this.checked = true;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

> without using a for loop

At some point, you're going to need some form of loop. Are you just hoping to abstract it?

`NodeList`s are `Array`-like, so you can [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) methods from `Array.prototype`, including [iterators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Iteration_methods) like [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). An example [from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/NodeList#Workarounds):

> Another approach without extending the DOM:
>
> ```
> var forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
>
> var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
> forEach.call(links, function(link){ // works in most browsers (please document here if you find browsers where it doesn't)
>   link.style.color = '#0F0';
> });
> ```

But note that even `forEach()` [depends on a loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Compatibility) (`while` in this case).